# MsgBox event loop and .show()

Tags: c++, qt

I currently have a problem where my QMessageBox has to be closed twice before it finally goes away. I was wondering if the local event loop QMessageBox::exec() is being triggered twice by the QApplication::exec() but I am not sure if that's right assumption to make. I then decided to switch the QMessageBox::exec() to .show() and the QMessageBox instantly disappears, not sure why I either. An explanation and a solution would be great.

```
#include "texteditor.h"
#include "./ui_texteditor.h"
TextEditor::TextEditor(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::TextEditor)
    , m_texteditor(new QTextEdit(this))
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    connect(ui->actionAbout, &QAction::triggered, this, &TextEditor::on_actionAbout_triggered);
    connect(ui->actionExit, &QAction::triggered, [](){  QApplication::quit();});
}

TextEditor::~TextEditor()
{
    delete ui;
}

void TextEditor::on_actionAbout_triggered()
{
    const QString projectName = QString("Project Name: %1").arg(PROJECT_NAME);
    const QString version = QString("Version: %1").arg(TextEditor_VERSION);
    QMessageBox msgBox(this);
    msgBox.setText(projectName);
    msgBox.setInformativeText(version);
    msgBox.exec();
    msgBox.show();
}
```

Comment: I can tell you why `show()` doesn't work. `show()` is non-blocking, it shows the window and returns immediately. At which point the calling function reaches the closing brace, `msgBox` object goes out of scope and is destroyed, taking the window with it. `exec()` should work though; I'm not sure what you mean by "has to be closed twice".

Comment: So I close it and then it  reappears for a second time. After closing the second time it does not reappear.

Comment: My guess would be, `on_actionAbout_triggered` is called twice for some reason. `QMessageBox` is a red herring, the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: why you use both of show and exec?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik isn't it just double called due to a. its name b. manual connection via connect(`connect(ui->actionAbout, &QAction::triggered, this, &TextEditor::on_actionAbout_triggered);`)? Isn't [that](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetaobject.html#connectSlotsByName) usually called by `setupUi?` That would explain it imho.

Comment: @AustinPennyfeather please rename `on_actionAbout_triggered` into sth else, possibly not matching the on_childObject_signal pattern and check if the problem persists. If, so `QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName` is the culprit.

Comment: @alagner what you said was correct. You should post it as an answer. So I can accept/mark it as the best answer. This way, it can be useful to other people. Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As is turned out during the discussion in the comments:
Either `on_actionAbout_triggered` should be renamed, possibly into something not matching the `on_childObject_signal` pattern or the manual connection `connect(ui->actionAbout, &QAction::triggered, this, &TextEditor::on_actionAbout_triggered);` should be removed.

The reason for the dual call is [QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetaobject.html#connectSlotsByName), which is usually (and also in this case) called by `setupUi`. It automatically connects the methods matching `on_childObject_signal` naming convention to their name-designated signals.